# JRebel does not reload JSPs with JBoss 4.2.3 and NetBeans (or Eclipse)

Tags: java, jsp, jrebel

JRebel works with all classes but not with JSPs.
It is a maven project and both with Eclipse and Netbeans it does not reload (JSPs). 
Anybody encountered a similar situation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I had some Problems with JRebel and Debugmode. Server was Glassfish though... But beside that everything works fine.

Comment: Have you pointed JRebel to static files with a `<web>` tag in `rebel.xml`? http://manuals.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/standalone/config.html#web

Comment: as it was pointed out by @binoternary, you should map the directory where JSPs are with rebel.xml. If you think you have done it correctly, and it still doesn't work, please ask from JRebel support: enable JRebel logging (-Drebel.log=true) and send the log file to support along with the problem description.